# App keeps stopping with TextView.setText() method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android programming and I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. 
My code: 
[image]

Every time I run the code, the emulator works just fine, but when I try to open the app it show the error message.
[image]

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What does the logcat says ?

Answer (score 1):

*first* you must inflate your layout by `setContentView` method .

*second* in `onCreate` method , bind your view .

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);
        TextView tf1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tf0);
        tf1.setText("Hello World!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call `setContentView` before calling `findViewById`.

```
void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate()

  setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout)
  TextView tf1 = findViewById(R.id.tf0)
  tf1.setText("hello")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `SetContentView(R.layout.your_layout)` before calling `findViewById`.

For example:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
tf1 = findViewById(R.id.tf0);
tf1.setText("text")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `tf1` is null because the layout hasnt been inflated yet also `setContentView(view)` is required to be called in `onCreate` to inflate the view. Also at the point you are declaring the `tf1` (outside `onCreate`) the reference will be null.

Try this

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tf1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tf0);
        tf1.setText("Hello World!");
    }
```